# Why most of the email validations pass something@something as a valid email address?

Tags: email-validation

As per my understanding email addresses are of the form `address@domaim.tld`. Still most of the email validations, including default html 5 and reactive form validations pass `something@abc` as a valid email. Can somebody provide an explanation on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer "abc" is a valid domain name.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Domain

Comment: Sorry I didn't know emails can be for this form also (something@something)